# ValidatesOnExceptions fires but it doesn't show the exception message

Tags: wpf, validation, binding

I have a TextBox.TextProperty bound to a ViewModel property. In the binding I have explicitly set **ValidatesOnExceptions** to **True**.

In resources the TextBox has this trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
   <Setter 
      Property="ToolTip"
      Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
   <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Crimson"/>
```

Unfortunately my implementation does not work perfectly because when I have an exception the TextBox background is highlighted with the **Crimson** color, but the tooltip text contains **"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."** instead of the message I wrote in the exception constructor.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the validation code is being invoked via reflection. Any caught exceptions will be wrapped up in a [TargetInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx) instance. The original exception will be stored as this exception's [InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx).

---

What happens if you bind to the [ValidationError.Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationerror.exception.aspx) property instead of [ValidationError.ErrorContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationerror.errorcontent.aspx)?

Comment: Good catch Stu!

If a bind to Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].Exception I get in the tooltip the whole exception Message.

Then I tried to bind to:
(Validation.Errors)[0].Exception.InnerException.Message
and I finally got the excpected one. 

But now...is the behavior of ValidatesOnExcpetions correct?

Comment: There does seem to be something strange going on in your validation - I think you need to work out why your exception is being wrapped in the first place. Binding to the inner exception is a bit brittle 'cos it'll stop working if you have any unwrapped exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same issue and I can't see why in my case validation is being invoked through reflection.  I'm considering one of two solutions.

First I'm thinking to implement a converter to extract the InnerException from the ValidationError.Exception when necessary.  Something like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ValidationError), typeof(string))]
public class ErrorContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var validationError = (ValidationError)value;

        if ((validationError.Exception == null) || (validationError.Exception.InnerException == null))
            return validationError.ErrorContent;
        else
            return validationError.Exception.InnerException.Message;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

I'm using the converter on the Tooltip message:

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
        Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem, Converter={StaticResource ErrorContentConverter}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Alternatively, I thought to use the UpdateSourceExceptionFilter on the Binding.  I've implemented a filter as below.  This solution is kind of a pain to use because you have to set the UpdateSourceExceptionFilter property in the code behind.

```
object InnerExceptionFilter(object bindingExpression, Exception exception)
{
    if (exception.InnerException != null)
    {
        var be = (System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression)bindingExpression;
        var rule = be.ParentBinding.ValidationRules.First(x=>x is ExceptionValidationRule);
        return new ValidationError(rule, be, exception.InnerException.Message, exception.InnerException);
    }
    else
        return exception;
}    
usage:
public MyConstructor()
{
    myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).ParentBinding.UpdateSourceExceptionFilter
        = new UpdateSourceExceptionFilterCallback(InnerExceptionFilter);
}
```

The converter is simple but only changes the message that is shown.  The filter is a more complete solution but is unfriendly to work with on each binding.  Any comments would be **greatly** appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].Exception.InnerException.Message}